# How to comment in Android app 1.0.56?

Tags: support, android-app

How can I comment on questions and answers in the stackexchange Android app 1.0.56?

I can't find it, was this feature removed?

Maybe I only don't see the button...
Thanks.

PS: the message with the required tags (support, bug, ..) is too short, I have to wait to see it again...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh man so weird... There were too many comments, so I was looking in the "...more" section next to "share".

Edit: I think the button wasn't shown to me, because I had no account yet at meta SE. With asking this question the button appeared, because an account was created automatically.